# CheckBox to get Y or N in c#?

Tags: c#, checkbox

I have corpflag check box when ever it is TRUE or FALSE i will get 1 or 0.How can i use CheckBox to get Y or N.

Code for Corp_flag Checkbox:

```
 this.chk_CorpFlag = new System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox();

if (dtGridNwBrandModel.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[10].Value.ToString().ToLower() == "false")
  {
     chk_CorpFlag.Checked = false;
  }
   else
  {
     chk_CorpFlag.Checked = true;
  }
```

Comment: Whats wrong with 1 and 0?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `Tag`

```
//I took the chance to make code more readable
using System.Windows.Forms;

var cellValue = dtGridNwBrandModel.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[10].Value;

// I suggest checking for true instead...
var isChecked = !(cellValue.ToString().ToLower() == "false");

this.chk_CorpFlag = new CheckBox
{
    Checked = isChecked,
    Tag = isChecked ? 'Y' : 'N'
};
```

and then you have 'Y' and 'N' available through `chk_CorpFlag.Tag`.

Answer (score 0):

**Edited:** I guess it doesn't accept 'Y' and 'N'. If you want this to be in variable then you can use ternary operator like this

```
var result = chk_CorpFlag.Checked == true? 'Y' : 'N';
```

Comment: `result = chk_CorpFlag.Checked? Y : N`

Comment: Single `=` is assignment

Comment: @YuriyGalanter:Error Cannot implicitly convert type 'char 'to 'bool'

Answer (score 0):

Do not quite understand what you want ... Was that it?

```
char Y_or_N = (hk_CorpFlag.Checked) ? 'Y' : 'N';
```